# Java - Compile using .class file

Tags: java, import, compilation, .class-file

I have the following java class:

```
public class ExampleClass{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Operation op1 = new Operation();
    }
}
```

And then in another location I have this class:

```
public class Operation{
    public int value;
}
```

Is it possible to create a new Operation object in ExampleClass WITHOUT directly importing Operation in ExampleClass. I want to compile de Operation.java, then copy the resulted Operation.class file to the location of ExampleClass and use this file to compile ExampleClass.java. Is such a thing possible ?

Comment: Why would you want to do something like that?

Comment: @Amongalen I am building a RMI application and I want to send the .class file from the server to the client.

Comment: You are trying to solve a problem that doesn’t exist. You can compile your `ExampleClass` using the `Operation.class`, just as you want, without any problems. There is no requirement to have the source code of `Operation` available. That’s how you compile your code against the JDK classes, as well as 3rd party libraries, without the need to have their source code at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get new instance of Operation by reflection without import it in code.

```java
try {
    Class.forName("package.Operation").getConstructor().newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

replace `package.Operation` with the package of `Operation` class.

Comment: Did you test that this code works ? It doesn't for me. First thing first : `A` is undefined.

Comment: @ROBlackSnail A is a placeholder. In your example, you should replace it with Operation.

Comment: @ROBlackSnail Oh I'm sorry that part of the code was copied by mistake. i deleted it. the part in try block is the answer.

Comment: @SMortezaSA So now that I have this new instance, can I do anything with it ? Say can I print the integer `value` of this instance ?

Comment: @ROBlackSnail Yes, you can do that with relection. read [Using Java Reflection](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html).

Comment: @ROBlackSnail and read [Reflection in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reflection-in-java/).